# phpseclib 3.0 : Must be connected to a terminal. bash: line 1: ./file.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: php, bash, command, execute, phpseclib

I have a problem. Indeed, I made a connection system via SSH, with phpseclib3. I can connect, take a screen of the console.
But the problem, I can't execute with, commands like:

1. screen -x 394987.bot
2. ./bot.sh

It tells me the following error: Must be connected to a terminal. bash: line 1: ./bot.sh: No such file or directory

My code:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; 
use phpseclib3\Net\SSH2;
use phpseclib3\File\ANSI;


$key = "Ahahah my good password lol";
$ssh = new SSH2('my_best_ip_lol', 22);   // Domain or IP
if (!$ssh->login('root', $key))   exit('CONNEXION SSH PERDUE. VERIFIEZ LES DONNEES DE CONNEXION SSH'); 
$ansi = new ANSI;

$ansi->appendString($ssh->read('root@vps:~/BOT$'));
echo $ssh->write("screen -x 394987.bot\n");
echo $ssh->write('./bot.sh');

$ssh->setTimeout(2);
$ansi->appendString($ssh->read());
echo $ansi->getScreen();

echo $ssh->exec("screen -x 394987.bot");
echo $ssh->exec('./bot.sh');
```

Thank you,

Comment: `screen` requires a terminal. You can probably try to run it in detached mode (i.e, pass the `d` and `m` flags, more info the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)). You probably also lack the `bot.sh` script in the dir you're in, double check it.

Comment: @nitrin0 Well no, I managed in my "$ansi->getScreen();" to get the "screen", and to put "./bot.sh" on the writable area.

Comment: `$ansi->appendString($ssh->read('root@vps:~/BOT$')); echo $ssh->write("screen -x 394987.bot\n");`. You should probably do `$ansi->appendString($ssh->read('root@vps:~/BOT$'));` after that. I say that because normally, in bash, there _is_ a delay between when two successive commands are ran. With phpseclib there isn't and sometimes the gap between these two commands is too short for Linux to be able to do anything with